# Bootstrap v4 popover hidden events

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, events, popover

I have a bootstrap popover which all works correctly so far.

However Im having trouble events. The show.bs.popover and shown.bs.popover events work as expected however hide and hidden events dont seem to fire.

```
$('#element').popover({ >options here< })
.popover('show')
.on('show.bs.popover', function() {
...
})
.on('shown.bs.popover', function() {
...
})
.on('hidden.bs.popover', function() {
alert('hidden'); //NOT WORKING
});
```

Im miss understanding somewhere. Maybe the hidden code needs to run later. Maybe the popover doesnt exist when this function is being called.

So Ive also tried fetching the popover id and calling it like this ...

```
$('#popover_id').on('hidden.bs.popover', function() {
alert('hidden'); //NOT WORKING
});
```

But this doesnt seem to work either.

Any suggestions would be great!!

Answer (score 0):

Check out this snippet, it works just fine. Be sure you clicked the button twice to get the alert box.

```js
$('#element').popover({ placement: 'bottom', content: 'Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus.' })
  .popover('show')
  .on('show.bs.popover', function() {
  })
  .on('shown.bs.popover', function() {
  })
  .on('hidden.bs.popover', function() {
    alert('hidden');
  });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/tether/1.4.0/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<button id="element" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">
  Popover on bottom
</button>
```

Comment: Thank you. This does work and the only difference is in the way you call it with the data attribute. Im not sure why it doesnt work programatically.

Comment: I've removed all the data attributes and still it works. Also check the references to the libraries' js files I included in the snippet. Maybe you have different version or some of them are missing

Answer (score 0):

So the issue I found to be was that when you show a popover programmatically using JavaScript and then use 'dispose' to remove it, the 'hide' and 'hidden' events are never fired despite in the bootstrap docs it saying that the 'dispose' function "hides and destroys a popover."